# Binding more knockout ViewModels to 1 View

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, navigation

I've Made several knockout ViewModels and now i'm trying to bind them to one ViewModel, but this doesn't work correctly!

It should work like a navigation. If the LoginModel is done it should skip to the start Model!

I have no idea how this could be made

How to do this?

```
<!-- Login Seite -->
<form data-bind="visible: userNotLoggedIn" action="" data-role="page" id="Login">

    //Some code

</form>
<!-- ----------------------------------  -->


<!-- Start Seite -->

<form data-bind="visible: showStart" action="" data-role="page" id="pageStart">

   //Some Code

</form>

<!-- --------------------------------------------------------------------- -->



<!-- Projekt Details-->
<form data-bind="visible: showDetails" action="" data-role="page" id="pageDetails">

   // SOME CODE

</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Login').live('pageinit', function (event) {
        ko.applyBindings(new LoginViewModel(), document.getElementById('Login'));
    });

    $('#pageStart').live('pageinit', function (event) {
    alert("Hallo");
        ko.applyBindings(new StartViewModel(), document.getElementById('pageStart'));
    });

    $('#pageDetails').live('pageinit', function (event) {
        alert("Hallo");
        ko.applyBindings(new DetailsViewModel(),document.getElementById('pageDetails'));
    });

</script>
Javascript for Knockout ViewModels:

function LoginViewModel() { //Some Code }

function StartViewModel() { //Some Code }

function DetailsViewModel() { //Some Code}
```

Comment: Could you please give some more detail about the problem? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No, it's just not working how it should work!

I have a Log-In Page with a LogIn-ViewModel!

If the LogIn is done it should skip to the StartViewModel, which is in the same page. 
The LogIn should be hidden..

Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: No It's just no working how it should! 

For example I have a LogIn-page and a Start-page. Both are in the same view and each page has it's own ViewModel!

If the LogIn is done it should go to the Start-Page, but now it just reloads the LogIn-Page

Do you know what i mean?

Comment: Sorry I can't say I do... could you perhaps recreate the problem in JSFiddle and then link to it? Then I can hopefully take a look and see it straight off.

Comment: Sorry!
I'm not able to reproduce my problem in jsFiddle!

I'll try to explain it better!


I have an application which is one View.
This View should handle 3 pages ("Login","Start","Details").
There should be an ViewModel for each of these Pages.
Only one  Page is available! For example if i am on the Login Page i'm not able to go to the Start-page until i am logged in correctly!

Comment: A view shouldn't handle multiple pages. You have 3 views: Login, Start and details so you'll need to create 3 views and 3 viewModels to go along with it. You are trying to hack the functionality of MVVM a bit with this approach.

Comment: the problem with that is, that this application should run offline.

So this has to be all in one View so it is loaded only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly you are trying to split a page into three interchangeable view models - Login, Start, Detail.

This could be easily done by grouping them into one master view model. And placing each part in a annonymous template (or knockout 'if' comment blocks).

```
var masterViewModel = {
    loginVM: ko.observable(),
    detailsVM: ko.observable()
};

var LoginVM = function () {
    this.showDetails = function () {
        masterViewModel.loginVM(null);
        masterViewModel.detailsVM(new DetailsVM());
    };
};

var DetailsVM = function () {
    this.showLogin = function () {
        masterViewModel.loginVM(new LoginVM());
        masterViewModel.detailsVM(null);
    };
};

masterViewModel.loginVM(new LoginVM()); 

ko.applyBindings(masterViewModel);​

<!-- ko template: { 'if': loginVM, data: loginVM } -->  
    <h1>This is the login</h1>  
    <button data-bind="click: showDetails">Show Details</button>  
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko template: { 'if': detailsVM, data: detailsVM } -->  
    <h1>These are the details</h1>  
    <button data-bind="click: showLogin">Show Login</button>  
<!-- /ko -->
```

Here is a complete sample in a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/angelyordanov/edT79/.

Comment: Please click the check mark bellow the answer to "Accept" it if it answers your question, Thanks.

Comment: I have a problem again,
The user observable is undefined? 
What am i doing wrong? I have a problem again,
The user observable is undefined? 
What am i doing wrong?

Here is my js fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4A87x/1/

Comment: You are not using the `data-bind` attribute. In your html replace `type='value: user'` with `data-bind='value: user'`.

Comment: thank you! 
i have no idea how i couldn't have noticed this mistake